# Storing an image file in an object (without needing the file afterwards)

Tags: c#, image, serialization, storage

I've looked everywhere, but can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

I'm making a personal app to store information, and one of the things I would like stored within the DB file is a thumbnail for each entry.  I have loaded the pictures from files, but I would like to be able to save the DB without needing the file to be physically present afterwards.  In other words, I would like the separate the image variable from its file, but still keep the image data within that variable.

I don't really have a snippet to post, as I'm not sure how to approach this problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I'm using a picturebox to load the image, and have an image variable in my object, but when I store the file in that image, it still requires the .jpg to be where I selected it from...

EDIT: I should be more specific, I'm not using SQL or anything like that, I'm simply serializing the object used to store my database into a file.  I guess I'm using "db" in a more general sense...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following approaches:

1. Use WPF and the [System.Windows.Media.Imaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.aspx) namespace
2. Use COM Interop with the WIC interfaces (see http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wictools for WicCop which contains an export of all of the APIs for C#).
3. The [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class can also be helpful for you if you wanna do something rudiementary like read an image from from the disk and write it to another stream to save in the DB.

Comment: So, if I serialize it to a file like I would normally do for my other object collections (using a stream and bformatter), when I deserialize the object, it won't require that file to be where I originally loaded it from?

Comment: Not sure which API you are referring to, but in general "yes" it should not - given that you closed the file handle by using "using" or explicitly calling .Close() oin the file stream.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on what type of database you are using but...

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server and the size of the files don't exceed the max (2 gig) then I would use [VarBinary(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx).

Then you just have to read the bytes back into a the image source.  Telerik has a cool [binary image control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/binaryimage.aspx) that just lets you throw raw binary data at it.